# induction with binomial coefficients 6

Tags: induction, binomial-coefficients

I have this as a homework so please no full answers.I know how induction works but as i read this little explanation it becomes very vague what to do and what i actually need to prove? Can someone give a tip?

[image: the q]

Comment: Hint: Pascal's Triangle.

Comment: Hint : $$\binom{n}{r}+\binom{n}{r+1}=\binom{n+1}{r+1}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When r is equal to 1, then ${n}\choose{r}$ $=$ ${n}\choose{1}$ $= n$. So the sum, ${r}\choose{r}$ + ${r+1}\choose{r}$ + ... becomes $1 + 2 + ... + n = n(n-1)/2$ $=$  ${n}\choose{2}$ which is the triangle formula.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: This is sometimes called the hockeystick identity:

[image]

Comment: Nice visualization! (+1)